Family sent back to Medieval times, dad almost gets decapitated
I am trying to remember a movie or TV show that might be from either the 1980s or the 1990s. I keep thinking it's Honey I Shrunk the Kids, but there was no episode I can find like that. Maybe there is one. I remember a scene where the family is sent to I think the medieval times. The dad almost gets decapitated. The family is chased by a man with a yellow jacket and maybe orange hair. He is the villain of the movie. That's all I remember. Maybe this was a dream I don't know.

How did they go into the past? How did the dad almost get decapitated? Was the villain also from the present? Any other details will help. This is precious little to go on.

This could be Stay Tuned.

The dad almost gets decapitated.



The family is chased by a man with a yellow jacket


Trailer:



